# Implementing Bellman-Ford in python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I'm trying to adapt a Bellman-Ford graph algorithm in Python to my needs.

I've worked out the parsing part from a json file.

Here is the Bellman Ford code I found on github:
https://github.com/rosshochwert/arbitrage/blob/master/arbitrage.py

And here is my code I adapted from it:

```
import math, urllib2, json, re


def download():
    graph = {}
    page = urllib2.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries")
    jsrates = json.loads(page.read())

    result_list = jsrates["result"]
    for result_index, result in enumerate(result_list):
        ask = result["Ask"]
        market = result["MarketName"]
        pattern = re.compile("([A-Z0-9]*)-([A-Z0-9]*)")
        matches = pattern.match(market)
        if (float(ask != 0)):
            conversion_rate = -math.log(float(ask))
            if matches:
                from_rate = matches.group(1).encode('ascii','ignore')
                to_rate = matches.group(2).encode('ascii','ignore')
                if from_rate != to_rate:
                    if from_rate not in graph:
                        graph[from_rate] = {}
                    graph[from_rate][to_rate] = float(conversion_rate)
    return graph

# Step 1: For each node prepare the destination and predecessor
def initialize(graph, source):
    d = {} # Stands for destination
    p = {} # Stands for predecessor
    for node in graph:
        d[node] = float('Inf') # We start admiting that the rest of nodes are very very far
        p[node] = None
    d[source] = 0 # For the source we know how to reach
    return d, p

def relax(node, neighbour, graph, d, p):
    # If the distance between the node and the neighbour is lower than the one I have now
    if d[neighbour] > d[node] + graph[node][neighbour]:
        # Record this lower distance
        d[neighbour]  = d[node] + graph[node][neighbour]
        p[neighbour] = node

def retrace_negative_loop(p, start):
    arbitrageLoop = [start]
    next_node = start
    while True:
        next_node = p[next_node]
        if next_node not in arbitrageLoop:
            arbitrageLoop.append(next_node)
        else:
            arbitrageLoop.append(next_node)
            arbitrageLoop = arbitrageLoop[arbitrageLoop.index(next_node):]
            return arbitrageLoop


def bellman_ford(graph, source):
    d, p = initialize(graph, source)
    for i in range(len(graph)-1): #Run this until is converges
        for u in graph:
            for v in graph[u]: #For each neighbour of u
                relax(u, v, graph, d, p) #Lets relax it


    # Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles
    for u in graph:
        for v in graph[u]:
            if d[v] < d[u] + graph[u][v]:
                return(retrace_negative_loop(p, source))
    return None

paths = []

graph = download()

print graph

for ask in graph:
    path = bellman_ford(graph, ask)
    if path not in paths and not None:
        paths.append(path)

for path in paths:
    if path == None:
        print("No opportunity here :(")
    else:
        money = 100
        print "Starting with %(money)i in %(currency)s" % {"money":money,"currency":path[0]}

        for i,value in enumerate(path):
            if i+1 < len(path):
                start = path[i]
                end = path[i+1]
                rate = math.exp(-graph[start][end])
                money *= rate
                print "%(start)s to %(end)s at %(rate)f = %(money)f" % {"start":start,"end":end,"rate":rate,"money":money}
    print "\n"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "belltestbit.py", line 78, in <module>
    path = bellman_ford(graph, ask)
  File "belltestbit.py", line 61, in bellman_ford
    relax(u, v, graph, d, p) #Lets relax it
  File "belltestbit.py", line 38, in relax
    if d[neighbour] > d[node] + graph[node][neighbour]:
KeyError: 'LTC'
```

When I print the graph I got everything needed. It is 'LTC' because it is the first one the list. I tried executing and filtering LTC, it gives me the same error with the first name coming on the graph:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "belltestbit.py", line 78, in <module>
    path = bellman_ford(graph, ask)
  File "belltestbit.py", line 61, in bellman_ford
    relax(u, v, graph, d, p) #Lets relax it
  File "belltestbit.py", line 38, in relax
    if d[neighbour] > d[node] + graph[node][neighbour]:
KeyError: 'NEO'
```

I don't see how could I fix this.

Thanks everyone.

PS: It appears that an answer was deleted, I'm new to SO, so I don't know what happened. I edited the post, because the answer helped me to advance :)

Comment: I sadly haven't got time to help you but I added some tags in the hope that the question gets traction. Also, "explaining" a line is a bit borderline for SO, so it'd be safer to be able to cite a concrete expected output.

Comment: Thanks @errantlinguist, dully noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Note that although you can find "inefficiencies" in this way, the chances you could actually use them to earn money are quite low. Most probably you would actually loose some money. AFAICS from the data I've seen during testing, those "inefficiencies" come from the fact that exchange rates are more volatile over course of minutes than the Bid-Ask spread. So what you see as an inefficiency is probably just a stale data and you can't actually execute all the required orders fast enough for the exchange rate to be stable enough to earn money. So be advised that ***you might loose your money*** if you try to use this application for anything more than your curiosity.

So now to the business:
Your data is in a different format than the one that the original code was designed for. Typical piece of data looks like this:

```
{
    "MarketName": "BTC-ETH",
    "High": 0.05076884,
    "Low": 0.04818392,
    "Volume": 77969.61816991,
    "Last": 0.04978511,
    "BaseVolume": 3875.47491925,
    "TimeStamp": "2017-12-29T05:45:10.18",
    "Bid": 0.04978511,
    "Ask": 0.04986673,
    "OpenBuyOrders": 4805,
    "OpenSellOrders": 8184,
    "PrevDay": 0.04955001,
    "Created": "2015-08-14T09:02:24.817"
}
```

What you are interested in is `MarketName`, `Bid` and `Ask`. And you need to understand what those [`Bid` and `Ask`](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/can-someone-explain-a-stocks-bid-vs-ask-price-relative-to-current-price) mean. Roughly speaking the `Ask` value means that if you want to sell `BTC` for `ETH` there is (or rather was not too long ago) a buyer who is willing to buy your `BTC` using exchange rate `0.04986673 BTC` for `1 ETH`. Similarly the `Bid` value means that if you want to sell `ETH` for `BTC` there is (was) a buyer who is willing to buy your `ETH` using exchange rate `0.04978511 BTC` for `1 ETH`. Note that this structure means that you will not have a record with `"MarketName": "ETH-BTC"` because it provides no additional data.

So knowing that you can fill your `graph` with proper distances, which are logarithms of the corresponding rates. Also I believe that there is another bug in your code: since the argument `p` of the `retrace_negative_loop` is actually dictionary of predecessor nodes, `retrace_negative_loop` returns the negative loop in the reverse order. And since your graph is directed the same loop might be positive in one direction and negative in the other one.

```
import math, urllib2, json, re


def download():
    graph = {}
    page = urllib2.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries")
    data = page.read()
    jsrates = json.loads(data)

    result_list = jsrates["result"]
    for result_index, result in enumerate(result_list):
        ask = result["Ask"]
        bid = result["Bid"]
        market = result["MarketName"]
        pattern = re.compile("([A-Z0-9]*)-([A-Z0-9]*)")
        matches = pattern.match(market)
        if matches:
            from_rate = matches.group(1).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
            to_rate = matches.group(2).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

            # different sign of log is effectively 1/x
            if ask != 0:
                if from_rate not in graph:
                    graph[from_rate] = {}
                graph[from_rate][to_rate] = math.log(float(ask))
            if bid != 0:
                if to_rate not in graph:
                    graph[to_rate] = {}
                graph[to_rate][from_rate] = -math.log(float(bid))

    return graph  # Step 1: For each node prepare the destination and predecessor


def initialize(graph, source):
    d = {}  # Stands for destination
    p = {}  # Stands for predecessor
    for node in graph:
        d[node] = float('Inf')  # We start admiting that the rest of nodes are very very far
        p[node] = None
    d[source] = 0  # For the source we know how to reach
    return d, p


def relax(node, neighbour, graph, d, p):
    # If the distance between the node and the neighbour is lower than the one I have now
    dist = graph[node][neighbour]
    if d[neighbour] > d[node] + dist:
        # Record this lower distance
        d[neighbour] = d[node] + dist
        p[neighbour] = node


def retrace_negative_loop(p, start):
    arbitrageLoop = [start]
    prev_node = start
    while True:
        prev_node = p[prev_node]
        if prev_node not in arbitrageLoop:
            arbitrageLoop.append(prev_node)
        else:
            arbitrageLoop.append(prev_node)
            arbitrageLoop = arbitrageLoop[arbitrageLoop.index(prev_node):]
            # return arbitrageLoop
            return list(reversed(arbitrageLoop))


def bellman_ford(graph, source):
    d, p = initialize(graph, source)
    for i in range(len(graph) - 1):  # Run this until is converges
        for u in graph:
            for v in graph[u]:  # For each neighbour of u
                relax(u, v, graph, d, p)  # Lets relax it

    # Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles
    for u in graph:
        for v in graph[u]:
            if d[v] < d[u] + graph[u][v]:
                return retrace_negative_loop(p, v)
    return None




graph = download()

# print graph
for k, v in graph.iteritems():
    print "{0} => {1}".format(k, v)
print "-------------------------------"

paths = []
for currency in graph:
    path = bellman_ford(graph, currency)
    if path not in paths and not None:
        paths.append(path)

for path in paths:
    if path == None:
        print("No opportunity here :(")
    else:
        money = 100
        print "Starting with %(money)i in %(currency)s" % {"money": money, "currency": path[0]}

        for i, value in enumerate(path):
            if i + 1 < len(path):
                start = path[i]
                end = path[i + 1]
                rate = math.exp(-graph[start][end])
                money *= rate
                print "%(start)s to %(end)s at %(rate)f = %(money)f" % {"start": start, "end": end, "rate": rate,
                                                                        "money": money}

    print "\n"
```

Also the check `if path not in paths and not None:` is potentially not enough because it doesn't filter our `path`s that are just rotations of one another but I didn't bother with fixing that as well.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I thought about it all night and realised I missed that I also need all the pairs with with bid price. I was about to delete this since it was not a code error, but simply not possible. I don't intend to make any money of this, this is just for a class project, this was not needed but I wanted to do more and improve my coding skills for the future. I'll try to find a fix for the path. Also the fees are way to high on crypto brokers to make any money of this.

Comment: Would you think that it is possible to limit the computation of the algo to like a n number of nodes? At first I did it with the len(path) in the end, but then I realized that it would be faster to limit it when the computation happen. Long paths are not relevant where there is like more than 3 or 4 trades. Thanks

Comment: @mescu, I don't get your question. What computations do you want to limit and what for? There are not that many currencies in the world so it works fast anyway.

Comment: For exemple, it can computes a path that is : BTC->LTC->XRP->USDT->ADA->BTC, so it is not very relevant in the situation. So I tought that I could limit the graph to only get, for exemple, a maximum of 3 or 4 nodes from the starting point to get it to run faster.

Comment: @mescu, I still don't understand. If you don't intend this as a tool to actually try to earn money, in what sense cycle `BTC->LTC->XRP->USDT->ADA->BTC` is less relevant than any shorter paths? Generally you can try filter out longer loops but out of the top of my head I don't know any algorithm that efficiently finds all negative loops. So you can't filter them by any metric. Of course you can find just all elementary loops and then filter only negative from them but this probably would not be very efficient.

Comment: I also tried to find other algos for negative cycles, but couldnt find one. We have to do a paper on arbitrage of any kind whether possible or impossible, and we could take any subject, so I wanted to do it with cryptos. In real life situation more than 3 or 4 trades is not realistic that is why I wanted to filter them out. I'm outputing all the data in a csv file so I can analyze them. Even if I wanted to make money out this, which I think is not possible, it would much of hassle for not much, and I don't even have the skills to do it yet. Still young and a lot to learn. Thanks for your time!